# getting error "Unknown Server error" while using asyncfileupload in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asyncfileupload

i am using asyncfileupload control to upload a .csv file an read it and store the data in database here is what i am doing :

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="venfileupld" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="ProcessUpload" />
```

and here's the code:

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{


    string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    string dir = Server.MapPath("upload_excel/");
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, name);
    venfileupld.SaveAs(path);
    writetodb(path);
    fetch4();

}
```

now everything is working fine in my localhost ... but when i uploaded this in a hosted server then i am getting an error when i am uploading a file .. the error is :

```
"Unknown Server Error"
```

what should i do ... i am using updatepanel also ... but i am not sure that will cause this ..

**UPDATE:-**

so as i got the 1st ans yes its a codebehind issue ... 
here what i am doing now :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Admin1.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin1" %>
```

should i try :

```
CodeBehind:"Admin.aspx.cs"
```

then what should it `Inherits` ??

any help will be real helpfull

**More Update**

my .cs code starts like this :

```
  public partial class Admin1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     //all the codes
 }
```

Comment: Refresh the application pool &  restart the website. I t worked for me. Also I changed my sessionstate to InProc instead of stateserver in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

This problem you facing because of code-behind file is not found. check whether you are missing any code-behind files

Comment: i think yes u r right i debugged my whole project and found out that i am missing a code-behind file ... but i dont know any think about this what should i do?

Comment: should i convert my .cs files to .dll ??

Comment: @ArindamDas:  class name is admin or admin1 of codebehind file?

Comment: i dont have any namespase on have that class `admin1`

Comment: @ArindamDas:try this-CodeBehind:"admin1.aspx.cs"

Comment: see whether lowercase or uppercase

Comment: i tried this `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Admin1.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin1" %>` but getting an error saying can't load `admin1`

Comment: make again codefile & add partial keyword to admin class- public partial class admin1

Comment: @ArindamDas:youe class filename is Admin1 , make all small a to A

Comment: @ArindamDas:<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Admin1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin1" %>

Comment: yeah its running ... but its not running in my hosted server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact of the server file not being shared to IIS. Right click on the folder you are trying to save the file to, navigate to security settings and add/allow ILS/USERS to modify the folder. This will solve your problem.