# File upload error - Server Response Error: 'Unknown Server error'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload, server-response

I am trying to upload a file but I'm getting the error `Server Response Error: 'Unknown Server error'`

It's not even going into the function in the code behind so I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="fileUpload_UploadedComplete" />
```

The code never goes into the `fileUpload_UploadedComplete`.

```
protected void fileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following thread:
[getting error "Unknown Server error" while using asyncfileupload in asp.net using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467349/getting-error-unknown-server-error-while-using-asyncfileupload-in-asp-net-usin)

Also, include more details in your question so it will be easier to understand the complete scenario.

Comment: That thread didn't help. The code for uploading the file is in a user control which I then call from another page. It works being called on one page, but I get "Unknown Server Error" on another page.